# Why does DrawableGameComponent need to call base.Draw()?

Tags: c#, xna

I am creating a basic game in XNA / Monogame framework. I use a DrawableGameComponent so that its Draw() and Update() functions get called automatically.

So far, so good, but what I don't understand is what base.Draw() refers to in a DrawableGameComponent instance, and why you need it. In my example I can even leave it out and the game still runs fine.

Code excerpt: (questions in the comments)

Game1.cs

```
 protected override void Initialize()
        {
            Car car3 = new Car(this, new Vector2(450, 100), Color.GreenYellow);
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            SpriteBatch.Begin();
            // this calls Game.Draw - and this loops through all the game components and draws them
            base.Draw(gameTime);
            SpriteBatch.End();
        }
```

And Car.cs

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // this draws the car after Car.Draw() gets called by the Game class
            Game1.SpriteBatch.Draw(Texture,Position,Color);

            // but why do we call base.Draw here? The car is already drawn. 
            // and the DrawableGameComponent.Draw method is empty, so we dont really need to call that?
            // what's more, if I comment this code out, the game still works.
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because if you start to extend your Car class with for example, raceCar, bigCar, etc you may don't want to recode the draw function statments that you had write in the base car class. That's the main reason to use base.Draw() or base something in POO programming.

Comment: Yes, but in this case we're talking about the uppermost class that inherits directly from DrawableGameComponent. In that component the draw function is empty so there is no need to call it using base.Draw(). --- and that is actually the answer to my own question. base.Draw() can safely be removed.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: the base.Draw() line gets automatically inserted by the editor once you inherit from a class and override a function.

In this case, the parent class does not have any code inside Draw() so there is no need to call base.Draw() from within the child's Draw function.